# Discrete fourier transform on a large dataframe from time domain plot

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft, dft

We have a question about DFT in python. We have a large dataframe called 'walking' that looks like this:

```
             0
0      0.376798
1      0.382064
2      0.119208
3     -0.289914
4     -0.315472
...         ...
78459 -0.319814
78460 -0.379727
78461 -0.358384
78462 -0.313725
78463 -0.233994

[78464 rows x 1 columns]
```

This is a plot of our data in the time domain:

[image]

We would like plot our data in the frequency domain by conducting a discrete fourier transform. An example of what we want to achieve is this:

[image]

The left image is a plot from the time domain and the right picture a plot from the frequency domain.

We tried doing this with scipy.fft and numpy.fft.fft, but were unable to do it. This is our code using numpy:

```
ft = np.fft.fft(walking[0])/len(walking[0])
ft = ft[range(int(len(walking[0])/2))]
plt.plot(abs(ft))
plt.show()
```

Could someone help us?

Comment: What do you mean by "... were unable to do it"?

Comment: We could not perform a discrete fourier transform from the time domain plot to a frequency domain plot. We dont know how to do a discrete fourier transform